# Pandas: efficiently exclude rows basing on criteria spanning all columns

Tags: python, optimization, pandas

I have a DataFrame, which, simplified, can look like this:

```
ID     A    B    C
ID_1   0    1    1
ID_2   0    0    0
ID_3   1    1    0
```

And so on. What I need to do is to *remove* rows where "1" is present in more than 50% of the columns.

I came up with this function, using `apply`:

```
def thresh_filter(value):
    counts = value.value_counts(True) # Fraction based counts
    if (counts.index == 1).any():
        # Some rows are all 0s
        return counts[1] > 0.50
    else:
        return False
```

In an effort to make it faster, I also tried this solution:

```
def thresh_filter(value):
    counts = value.value_counts(True)
    max_idx = counts.idxmax()
    max_percentage = counts.max()
    return max_idx == 1 and max_percentage > 0.50
```

And then use it with

```
result = mydf.apply(thresh_filter, axis=1)
```

The problem is that it's **very** slow. On a 50K line DataFrame with 24 columns it takes several seconds, which makes it quite not viable.

What can be done to improve its efficiency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values are really only 1 and 0, you could try using `df.sum(axis=1)` and then check if the total is greater than half of the number of columns.  For instance, if you have 10 columns, do `df[df.sum(axis=1)<=5]`.

Comment: Yes, they are only 1 and 0 ("quasi" binary flags). I'll check this solution.

Comment: Tested, works nicely and it's orders of magnitude faster. Thanks!